# Run script A inside a script B, and then exit script B without exiting script A

Tags: bash, loops, run-script

I'm writing a test for a script which I have written and works like the simplest tr command. My idea for a test was that I would run in parallel tr command and my script, save output to variables and compare the variables. First of all, how to stop script from runnning forver? I enclose codes of both the test and my scipt. Secondly, how to save output of my script and tr to a variable? I've tried var=$(function), but it's not working. And is there a way to call them in parallel? Eg. I'll start the test and then write 'abba' and I would like both scripts to change it in pallalel to 'ABBA'.

And is it a good idea? I've never written 'formal' tests before.

Test code:

```
#!/bin/bash
 **tr_znakiScript="/home/wiktoria/skrypty/testy/tr_znaki.sh"
  echo "this script is about to run another script"
  a=ab
  b=AB
  echo "$a" 
  echo "$b"

  . $tr_znakiScript "$a" "$b"

  exit 1

 # x=2;
#while [ $x -le 2 ]; do
#echo "Napis pojawił się po raz: $x"
#x=$[x + 1]
#hash=$(. $tr_znakiScript "$a" "$b")
#. $tr_znakiScript "$a" "$b"
#echo $hash
#done
#echo $hash**
```

tr_znaki.sh code

```
#!/bin/bash
first_two="$1 $2" #zapisuje dwia pierwsze znaki do wspolnej zmiennej
a="$1";b="$2" #rozdziela znaki
split1=$(echo $a | fold -w 1) #rozdziela a na litery i wypisuje
split2=$(echo $b | fold -w 1) #rozdziela a na litery i wypisuje
arr1=($split1) #zapisanie stringu do tablicy
arr2=($split2) #zapisanie stringu do tablicy

shift #usuwa pierwszy argument
shift #usuwa drugi argument


size1=${#arr1[@]} #zapisanie rozmiaru arr1 do zmiennej
size2=${#arr2[@]} #zapisanie rozmiaru arr2 do zmiennej

# nieskończona pętla pozwalająca na ciągłe wpisywanie tekstu do translacji, przerywana standardowo ctrl + c
while true
do 
    read tekst #zmienna, do której wpisywany jest przez użytkownika tekst
    mod=$tekst #zapisanie wpisanego tekstu do zmiennej
    for (( i=0; i<${size1}; i++ ));  
    do
        mod=${mod//[${arr1[i]}]/${arr2[i]}} #nowa zmienna z zamianą którejś z wartości w arr na odpowiadającą wartość w arr2
    done
    echo $mod #wypisanie zmienionego tekstu
    #sleep 1 #czeka sekundę

done
```

Comment: Since you're using the `.` command, you are executing B's code in the same interpreter as A. So they are the same program.

Answer (score 2):

Try [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Example:

```
$(nohup ./your/script/here.sh > somefile.out 2> somefile.err < /dev/null &)
```

The nohup command basically allows you to run a process in the background, but in the meantime, you CAN NOT interact with the program by any means (except for terminating it). (See nohup docs for details)

You can check `somefile.out` for your output.

Also, for terminating you can use `top` (process manager) or `kill -SIGTERM PID` (this can be used in your script: `$(kill -SIGTERM PID)`). (PID is your Process ID, which can also be found in top.)

For comparing your outputs, you can use `./your/script/A.sh > file.out` and then you can use the `diff file.out somefile.out` for checking the differences of the two files.

Comment: `nohup` does not run a command in the background. `nohup` allows you to run a command which is immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty. This is also the reason you added a `&` at the end of the line, which does causes the command to be executed in the background.

Comment: There. Fixed with "allows you"